# Internet Explorer 10 hangs on G2PO.com but not Chrome

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I'd love to know why IE10 (possibly 9 too) hangs when loading www.g2po.com while Chrome doesn't. What can I do to further troubleshoot this issue? Is there a specific feature in IE's developer tools that I can use to help me identify the source of the problem? Is there other tools that can help?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask

Comment: It seems that @Alert Eltawil has met the very first statement of stack don't-ask: "You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face". I guess depending on your perspective. I was able to answer his question and it was a real problem he was facing.

Comment: Hmm. Well, @Brian was very helpful in determining what the problem was which lead me to update the site to fix it. Maybe I should have rephrased my question.

Comment: The question was pretty clear, in my opinion. If you visit the mentioned site in IE10 the site freezes IE10 for a while then loads but this behavior doesn't happen in Chrome. I was looking for code related reasons that caused this behavior specifically in IE10. The question was clear enough for @BrianOgden to give a straight and helpful answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not having any issues with it loading in IE10 on my machine, try adding to your header:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
```

This will force IE out of compatibility mode.

**UPDATE**
Yup, just double checked, it is IE10 Compatibility View that causes the "hanging"

Comment: Yup, that was it. Thanks!